# Summing Multiple Times in a Column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, df, of two columns, x and y. I am trying to sum values within column y and put the sums into another dataframe. The summing only occurs for a section of column y between NA values. There are multiple sections of column y that must be summed but I want each sum to be a separate value in the new data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1966,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,5622,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,7889), 
             y = c(NA,1,2,3,4,NA,9,8,7,6,NA))
```

The answer should be in the format of a data frame with one column of two rows:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(10,30))
```

I thought of solving this using some for loop and if statements for values between values of NA in column y. Any ideas?

So far, I have the following code, but I ultimately want it to work for a column with a series of more than two summations:

```
NAs <- which(is.na(df$y))
L1 <- length(NAs)
L0 <- dim(df)[1]
soln1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = L1-1, ncol = 1))
for(i in 1:L0){
for(j in 1:L1){
if (j == L1){
break
} else 
soln1[j,1] <- sum(df[NAs[j] +1,2]:df[NAs[j+1] -1,2])
}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example that illustrates what you'd like to do?

Comment: yes, please provide sample data that we can work with which will also better illustrate your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a stab at it with some fake data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,3,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1), 
                 y = c(1,2,NA,4,5,NA,7,8,NA,10,11,NA,13,14,NA,16))
#    df
#   x  y
#1  1  1
#2  1  2
#3  3 NA
#4  1  4
#5  3  5
#6  1 NA
#7  1  7
#8  1  8
#9  1 NA
#10 1 10
#11 3 11
#12 1 NA
#13 1 13
#14 1 14
#15 1 NA
#16 1 16
```

The magic function:

```
# sum rows in y if section is between NA values & before a value in column x that is > 2
specialSum <- function(x, y){
  starting <- which(c(NA,x[-length(x)]) > 2 & is.na(y))
  NAs <- which(is.na(y))
  L <- length(starting)
  ending <- sapply(1:L, function(z) NAs[NAs[-starting] > starting[z]][1])
  output <- matrix(NA, nrow = L)
  naming <- rep("",L)
  for(i in 1:L){
    output[i] <- sum(y[starting[i]:ending[i]], na.rm = T)
    naming[i] <- paste0(starting[i]+1,":",ending[i]-1)
  }
  dimnames(output) <- list(naming, "specialSum")
  output
}
specialSum(df$x, df$y)
#      specialSum
#7:8           15
#13:14         27
```

**EDIT:**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1966,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,5622,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,7889), 
                 y = c(NA,1,2,3,4,NA,9,8,7,6,NA))

specialSum <- function(y){
  NAs      <- which(is.na(y))
  starting <- NAs[-length(NAs)]+1
  ending   <- NAs[-1]-1
  L        <- length(starting)
  sums <- matrix(NA, nrow = L) ; naming <- rep("",L) # initialize for speed
  for(i in 1:L){
    sums[i]   <- sum(y[starting[i]:ending[i]], na.rm = T)
    naming[i] <- paste0(starting[i],":",ending[i])
  }
  sums <- sums[sums != 0,,drop = F] # in case there are multiple NAs in a row
  data.frame(specialSum = sums, row.names = naming)
}
specialSum(df$y)
#     specialSum
#2:5          10
#7:10         30
```

**EDIT#2:**

```
NAs <- which(is.na(df$y))
sumlist <- vector("list", length(NAs)-1)
count <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(i %in% NAs){
    count = count + 1
  } else {
    sumlist[[count]] <- append(sumlist[[count]], df$y[i])
  }
}
data.frame(specialSum = unlist(lapply(sumlist, sum))) # less pretty output
#  specialSum
#1         10
#2         30
```

Comment: I see this is on hold but am confident this answer successfully interprets the question. Ryan, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Evan, I like what you're thinking. Does my additional revision make sense to you?

Comment: The way your data example looks, do you ever have NAs where you don't want to sum? You write "Another way of thinking about this" and bring up the prior row being >2 but if this is optional, then all you really care about is summing values between NA in column y?

Comment: Okay, then see my EDIT and let me know if it does as you require

Comment: Your code works perfect! Do you know if it is possible to simply use for loop and if statements to solve this problem? This solution would be more similar to the code I posted in the problem statement. Thanks!